# Why can't Android Studio sync Gradle?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I'm not entirely sure how much information is needed for this error, but I'm trying to migrate a multi-project product from Eclipse to Android Studio. I can't get very far, though, because I get the below-screenshot error:

[image: A screenshot depicting the error, relevant code file, and overall file structure.]

As you see here, it says I should set the SDK directory in `local.properties`, but 
I have, and it's the correct location, and it still doesn't work. **How do I fix this error?**

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Open a terminal window, and execute the following commands:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/benleggiero/code/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
```

Then I would restart Android Studio.

Comment: Neither that nor `env ANDROID_HOME=/Users/benleggiero/code/android-sdk-macosx` worked. :/

Comment: Are you able to build a "Hello, World" application, or is this problem limited to the project you're trying to import?

Comment: yes, I can build a Hello World app and run it on a physical device.

Comment: In that case, there must be another SDK path defined somewhere in the project that is overwriting the one in your local.properties.  I'm not sure where it would be.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that it's also an Eclipse product?